# in quick-score library how to get key of searched item

Tags: javascript, quick-score

I am using [quick-score js package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/quick-score) to score my search result,
below is the code for same.

```
     var object= new QuickScore(['first name', 'last name', 'email id', 'phone number', 'company', 
        'enquiry', 'medium', 'source', 'stage', 'address', 'city', 'state', 'country', 
        'created at', 'personal details gender', 'personal details marital status', 
        'personal details date of birth', 'personal details referred by', 
        'spouse details first name', 'spouse details last name', 
        'spouse details nick name'] );

     var result= object.search("phone");
```

As a result, I am not getting the index of match, is there any way I can get the index from the match result.

below is the screenshot of the result object which I get from the quick score

[image]

**I want phone number index as item output result + value name **

i.e

```
[
  item : [ key : 4, value "phone number"]
]
```

Comment: There isn't any value "4" somewhere

Comment: I am saying i want index of that found value @Elikill58

Comment: Yes so in the case of your example, you want "0" ?